# transfer each value into other list

Tags: python

i want to make each value be in another list that i want this example below:

```
[['2', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['2', '-2'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '2'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '-3'], ['2', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '0'], ['4', '3'], ['2', '0']]
```

be like this:

```
[[['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['4']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['2'], ['-2']],
                               [['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['5']], [['3'], ['3']], [['4'], ['2']], [['3'], ['1']],
                               [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['-3']], [['2'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']],
                               [['3'], ['0']], [['4'], ['3']], [['2'], ['0']]]
```

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here's how you'd do it for a single sub-list:

```
out = [[elem] for elem in sub_list]
```

Since you want to do this for every sub-list in your main list:

```
out = [
        [[elem] for elem in sub_list]
        for sub_list in main_list
      ]
```

List comprehensions are wonderful things!

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda x: [[x[0]],[x[1]]], aa))
```

`aa` is your input list:

```
>>> aa
[['2', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['2', '-2'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '2'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '-3'], ['2', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '0'], ['4', '3'], ['2', '0']]
>>> list(map(lambda x: [[x[0]],[x[1]]], aa))
[[['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['4']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['2'], ['-2']], [['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['5']], [['3'], ['3']], [['4'], ['2']], [['3'], ['1']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['-3']], [['2'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['0']], [['4'], ['3']], [['2'], ['0']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [['2', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['2', '-2'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '2'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '-3'], ['2', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '0'], ['4', '3'], ['2', '0']]    
>>> b = [[[j] for j in i] for i in a]
>>> b
[[['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['4']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['2'], ['-2']], [['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['5']], [['3'], ['3']], [['4'], ['2']], [['3'], ['1']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['-3']], [['2'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['0']], [['4'], ['3']], [['2'], ['0']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sublists always contain two elements, you could do:

```
[[[a], [b]] for a,b in your_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

With recursion you can obtain what you want for a generic list with any level of nesting.

```
def make_sublists(ll):
    res = []
    for i in ll:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            res.append(make_sublists(i))
        else:
            res.append([i])
    return res
```

Using your example:

```
mylist = [['2', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['2', '-2'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '2'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '-3'], ['2', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '0'], ['4', '3'], ['2', '0']]
print(make_sublists(mylist))
```

you get your expected output.

```
[[['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['4']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['2'], ['-2']], [['2'], ['3']], [['1'], ['5']], [['3'], ['3']], [['4'], ['2']], [['3'], ['1']], [['3'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['-3']], [['2'], ['2']], [['4'], ['1']], [['3'], ['0']], [['4'], ['3']], [['2'], ['0']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your solution to work for an arbitrary number of elements in each sublist, check the one below:

```
inlist = [['2', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['2', '-2'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '2'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '-3'], ['2', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['3', '0'], ['4', '3'], ['2', '0']]
inlist = list(map(lambda elem: list(map(list,elem)),inlist))
print(inlist)
```